# AWS transcoded video is skipping first few seconds when playing the video using video view in android smart tv or devices

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-videoview, android-video-player, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Im facing an issue when i try to load **AWS transcoded videos** from server. This is happening only on few devices.
I download the videos(AWS transcoded) from server to local storage & play it with video view. In some android TVs & players especially running on OS Android-9, we are facing this issue where first **2-4 secs of video is skipped** & remaining will be played.

Is there any way to handle this issue or reason for getting this problem for only transcoded videos..!

**Attaching the details of original & transcoded video for reference**

[image: Video Details comparison]

Comment: I also have had the similiar issue, I solved it by using Exoplayer.

Comment: Can you provide any sample or reference doc for how you did it...

Comment: You can check out this Codelab, https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#2